# Using a c++ std::mutex declared inside a python object

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, c++11

Short question :
How can i Initialize a std::mutex in a structure after using malloc to get the corresponding memory?

More detail:
i'm trying to make a python module with a background thread

I create and run the thread without any problem, but if I try to use a mutex stored in the Python object, it crash.

If I define the mutex at the head of my cpp file, it works. But I would prefer to store it within the Device structure

In my PyDevice.h

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "structmember.h"

typedef struct sSharedData
{
    bool mStop;
} sSharedData;

typedef struct sDevice
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    std::thread mDataThread;
    std::mutex mDataThreadMutex;
    sSharedData mDataThreadSharedData;
} sLeddarDevice;


PyObject *StartDataThread( sLeddarDevice *self, PyObject *args );
PyObject *StopDataThread( sLeddarDevice *self, PyObject *args );

static PyMethodDef Device_methods[] =
{
    { "StartDataThread", ( PyCFunction )StartDataThread, METH_NOARGS, "Start the thread." },
    { "StopDataThread", ( PyCFunction )StopDataThread, METH_NOARGS, "Stop the thread." },
    { NULL }  //Sentinel
};

static PyMemberDef Device_members[] =
{
    { NULL }  //Sentinel
};

static PyTypeObject LeddarDeviceType =
{
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT( NULL )
    0,                              //ob_size
    "LeddarPy.Device",              //tp_name
    sizeof( sDevice ),        //tp_basicsize
    0,                              //tp_itemsize
    ( destructor )Device_dealloc,   //tp_dealloc
    0,                              //tp_print
    0,                              //tp_getattr
    0,                              //tp_setattr
    0,                              //tp_compare
    0,                              //tp_repr
    0,                              //tp_as_number
    0,                              //tp_as_sequence
    0,                              //tp_as_mapping
    0,                              //tp_hash
    0,                              //tp_call
    0,                              //tp_str
    0,                              //tp_getattro
    0,                              //tp_setattro
    0,                              //tp_as_buffer
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,             //tp_flags
    "Device object.",               // tp_doc
    0,                              //tp_traverse
    0,                              //tp_clear
    0,                              //tp_richcompare
    0,                              //tp_weaklistoffset
    0,                              //tp_iter
    0,                              //tp_iternext
    Device_methods,                 //tp_methods
    Device_members,                 //tp_members
    0,                              //tp_getset
    0,                              //tp_base
    0,                              //tp_dict
    0,                              //tp_descr_get
    0,                              //tp_descr_set
    0,                              //tp_dictoffset
    0,                              //tp_init
    0,                              //tp_alloc
    Device_new,                     //tp_new
};
```

And in my PyDevice.cpp

```
#include "LeddarPyDevice.h"
//Constructor
PyObject *Device_new( PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds )
{
    sLeddarDevice *self;

    self = ( sLeddarDevice * )type->tp_alloc( type, 0 );

    if( self != nullptr )
    {
        self->mDataThreadSharedData.mStop = false;
    }

    return ( PyObject * )self;
}

//Destructor
void Device_dealloc( sLeddarDevice *self )
{
    DebugTrace( "Destructing device." );
    Py_TYPE( self )->tp_free( ( PyObject * )self );
}

PyObject *StartDataThread( sLeddarDevice *self, PyObject *args )
{
    DebugTrace( "Starting thread" );
    self->mDataThreadMutex.lock();
    self->mDataThreadSharedData.mStop = false;
    self->mDataThreadMutex.unlock();
    self->mDataThread = std::thread( DataThread, self );

    Py_RETURN_TRUE;
}
```

It crashes whenever I try to use `self->mDataThreadMutex.lock()`.

Im not sure if the mutex is initialized correctly, i'm more used to pthread mutex where you need to initiliaze it manually.

Comment: StackOverflow is not `gdb`-as-a-service. Please post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is written in C and as such it won't run C++ constructors/destructors for you. And without them `std::mutex` is just a meaningless struct which will crash when used. What you need is [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) somewhere (after allocating `self`?):

```
self = ( sLeddarDevice * )type->tp_alloc( type, 0 );
new (self) sLeddarDevice {};
```

The second line calls the constructor of `sLeddarDevice` on `self` **without** allocating memory. That constructor will call constructors of each member as well.

You also have to manually call destructors when done: `self->~sLeddarDevice();`

You should **always** do that when combining C++ with Python. Otherwise in best case scenario you will leak memory. In worse case encounter undefined behaviour with random crashes.

Comment: Device_dealloc is called when the python object is deleted, I can call the destructor from there?

Comment: @DavidLevy Yes, you can and should. Note that I'm not sure how Python's `tp_alloc` and `tp_free` will work with C++'s constructors and destructors. Combining C++ with C code is tricky sometimes.

Comment: Using the constructor works (without the initialisation list), using the desctrutor cause a crash. A small detail, what does new (self) means? Its the first time I see new used this way

Comment: @DavidLevy It is called "placement new". It only runs the constructor without allocating memory (you pass the pointer to where it should call the constructor). See the link and/or google it. For the destructor: did you call it **before** `tp_free`?

Comment: Oh, note that the destructor will crash if you don't either `.join()` the thread or detach it.

Comment: Ok, everything works, i'll google more about placement new. My join wasnt properly done, causing the crash. Thanks for your time